# ZF2- Can't hide select options on Zend\Element\Select

Tags: javascript, zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm working on ZF2 and I'm trying to set two dependent dropdowns using javascript. I began to by trying to hide all options from the second select field when the firest is changed.

This is my form :

```
$this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'name' => 'category_list',
            'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Event category ',
                    'style' => 'display:none;',
                    'value_options' => array(
                                                ),
            ),

            'attributes'=> array(
                    'id'=>'list1',
                    'onchange'=>'hide()'
            )
    ));

    $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'name' => 'subcateg_list',
            'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Type Incident ',
                    'style' => 'display:none;',
                    'value_options' => array(
                                                )),
                    'attributes'=> array(
                            'id'=>'list2'
                    )
            ));
```

Note that the select fields are filled on the controller class !

And this is my Javascript function :

```
function hide()
    {
    var op = document.getElementById("list2").getElementsByTagName("option");
    for (var i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {

        ? op[i].disabled = true 
        : op[i].disabled = false ;
    } 
}
```

But when the first select field is changed nothing heppens. so where is the problem ?

Comment: The problem is in your js code within the for loop. Try to use jQuery instead of native JavaScript. It will be much easier and cleaner.

Comment: any example on how to use jQuery here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should throw a syntax error. The ternary oparator (?:) expects a condition to check against.
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript

```
(condition) ? alert('true') : alert('false');
```

As Fouad Fodail suggested -> a jQuery example:

```
function hide()
{
    $('#list2 option').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('disabled', condition);
                             // ^-- Do not forget to change this
    });
}
```

**Note:** The disabled attribute of the  tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 7 and earlier versions.
(http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp)

Another example, this will disable the second `<select id="select2">`, if the first `<select id="select1">` has been changed:

```
$('#select1').change(function() {
    $('#select2').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

*(untested)*

### Docs

- http://api.jquery.com/change/
- http://api.jquery.com/each/
- http://api.jquery.com/prop/